# Finding separating and processing repeatative blocks of lines with Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I wrote the script which analyze the text containing the  lines to be found:

```
Uplink Bytes:                   6168  Downlink Bytes:               40366
Uplink Packets:                   69  Downlink Packets:                72
Access list name     Pkts-Down Bytes-Down    Pkts-Up   Bytes-Up   
tcp                      14       3763         15       1622 
web                      58      36603         54       4546
<....>
```

It makes summation  of numbers in columns for strings with  individual access lists like tcp and web  then sum compared against total number in first 2 strings. I wrote the program which makes the job  with help of regualr expressions and result groups for these 3 types of strings.

Now I am thinking on how to make it work if there are few outputs like this in the text? What is most elegant way to achieve it?
I understand I need to reset the counters to 0 after processing the first block  and search again for all these 3 types of strings but how to do it the best way?
 Here is the current script:

```
import re


with open(input_file) as f:
            d_b = 0
            d_p = 0
            u_b = 0
            u_p = 0

    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        res = re.search('Uplink B\w+: +(\d+) +Downlink \w+: +(\d+)',line) 
        if (res):
            s_u_b = int(res.group(1))
            s_d_b = int(res.group(2))                        

        res = re.search('Uplink P\w+: +(\d+) +Downlink \w+: +(\d+)',line)
        if (res):    
            s_u_p = int(res.group(1))
            s_d_p = int(res.group(2))

        res = re.search('^[0-9a-zA-Z-_]+\ +(\d+) +(\d+) +(\d+) +(\d+) +\d+',line)   
        if (res):
            d_p += int(res.group(1))
            d_b += int(res.group(2))
            u_p += int(res.group(3))
            u_b += int(res.group(4))

if (d_b == s_d_b) and (u_b == s_u_b) 
and (d_p == s_u_p) and (u_p == s_u_p):
    print("No mismatch between subsession stats and ECS stats found")

else :
    print("Mismatch between subsession stats and ECS stats found:")
```

Comment: don't use `readlines`, just do `for line in f:`

Comment: also, don't use re. just do something like `if line.startswith(string): split and process here`. for the final lines (i.e. ones that don't start with 'Uplink' or 'Access', just try to split them and add them to your data.

Comment: Thanks but what if I have few blocks lie this  in 1 file. All I need to derive numbers and compare in each block separately for example:
    1st block
Uplink Bytes:     68  Downlink Bytes:     40
Uplink Packets:   69  Downlink Packets:    72

tcp                      14      34         15       16 
web                      58      36         54       45
<.> 2nd block
Uplink Bytes:                     6  Downlink Bytes:               3
Uplink Packets:                   9  Downlink Packets:             5
tcp                      11       376          15       1622 
udp etc..

Comment: if all blocks start the same way, then this is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I would introduce a notion of block boundary, which is seen when you match a line with `"Uplink Bytes:"` or an empty line (if one exists between these blocks).

At the time you detect as crossing into a new block, you reset all counters.

You could still process all lines one-by-one.

Depending on what you want to do with the data you compute for each block, you might want to encapsulate all of the counters and some related code into a small class.